# Insertion sort snippet in c aborts with Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

I tried a code in c to perform insertion sort(Ubuntu 14.04)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[10], i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, temp;
    printf("enter array elements\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if(a[i] < a[j]) {
                temp = a[i];
                for(k = i; k > j; k++) {
                   a[k]=a[k-1];
                }
                a[j]=temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("sorted array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf ("%d ",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then on terminal

```
~$gcc -Wall
~$./a.out
```

The program stopped abruptly with Segmentation fault after taking the input

I have tried a lot but failed miserably many times... I'm new to C so I need help...

What should I do??

Comment: Was a debugger used?

Comment: No... I went through stack overflow earlier and found out something called gdb... But I don't know how to debug with it

Comment: First Google result: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/

Comment: If you expect others to read your code, then please indent your code and use a conventional coding style.

Comment: replace `k > j;` with `k < j;` in for loop. you need to run loop upto when `k` is less than `j` otherwise it will k will keep on increasing and go out of bound.

Comment: You can run gdb like this:
Compile like this `gcc -Wall -g <filename>` then `gdb ./a.out`. Then start the program by typing `r` and `Enter`. After you have entered all input and the program crashes you can type `bt full` to see where it crashed. I get this: `(gdb) bt full
#0  0x0000000000400697 in main () at a.c:14
        a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9}
        i = 9
        j = 0
        k = 1128
        temp = 0`
In other words. The value of k is weird -> This part of your code seems wrong `for(k=i;k>j;k++)`

Comment: Used the debugger
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault
0x080485d8 in main () at insertsort.c:30
30                                        for(k=i;k>j;k++)
(gdb) c
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault
The program no longer exists
(gdb)

Comment: Thank-you guys... Solved the problem... My bad... Very silly... k-- not k++... In the loop.... But thanks a lot for teaching hour to work with debugger.... Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

Coding mistake

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[10], i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, temp;
    printf("enter array elements\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if(a[i] < a[j]) {
                temp = a[i];
                for(k = i; k > j; k--) {//insteadof k++
                   a[k]=a[k-1];
                }
                a[j]=temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("sorted array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf ("%d ",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```